# Is it possible to delete, let alone see, a file called "␀" on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, filesystems, filenames

There is a file on my Mac called `␀`, which is literally impossible to delete in OS X. I got access to Windows 8 and thought I could delete the file from there, but it's not even visible.

So are you able to delete, let alone see such a file in Windows 8?

Comment: open command prompt in the same folder as the file and type "dir" and hit enter. read through the listed file, do you see your file in it?

Comment: Where are you seeing this file? What else can you tell us about it (how big is it?;...)?

Comment: @RACING121 It's on my Desktop, zero bytes (since I opened it up in `nano` and cleared everything out. There's also a folder on my desktop which is 136 byte.

Comment: On OSX terminal the `bash` command, `rm -i ?` will step through all the single-character file names. When it gets to `\000` allow the deletion.

Comment: @AFH Doesn't work, I get "Invalid argument". The file cannot be deleted on OS X. I am look for how to delete it on Windows.

Comment: Try if you can delete it using short filenames. You can see the short names using dir /x

Comment: Wait, is it named the Unicode character you have in your post, or is it an actual null?

Comment: @BenN The character.

Comment: I thought the file name was a literal null character - thank you @BenN for clarifying this point. `rm -i ?` works perfectly on a file named `␀` in Ubuntu on an `ext4` file system. Things to try: (1) if the file appears in a GUI file manager, delete from there; (2)  - if `echo ?` shows `␀`, try  `echo ?|xargs rm`; (3) move all the other files to a different folder, then enter `rm *`; or (4) move up a directory level and enter `rm -r DirName`. All of these work in Ubuntu/Nautilus.

Comment: Deleting a file named that from the Windows command prompt works, though it appears as a question mark when you paste that character.

Comment: @AFH I've tried practically everything, any combination of `rm`, including the ones you provided, give me `Invalid argument`. Trying to move, rename or delete the file in a GUI (Finder in my case) gives me "error code -50". Removing the parent directory deletes everything in that directory except the actual directory and the file named `␀ `.  All of this is why I tried doing this in Windows.

Comment: Oh dear. It is beginning to look like a problem associated with the file system. Can you delete from Windows `explorer`? If not, try booting an Ubuntu Live system after disabling journalling as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/hfsplus). You should be able to delete from the file manager (Nautilus). (The reason I suggest using a GUI is that it avoids the very complex line parsing in `bash`.)

Comment: @AFH, the files are invisible in Windows, like I said in the question. I have no experience with Linux/GNU, but it looks like I might have to install that then.

Comment: You don't need to install it. You can do all you need by running it from a bootable DVD or USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some investigation your problem seems more complicated than i initially thought. To clarify, the original question seems to be IMHO: How to delete a file or directory containing the Unicode null character from a HFS+ disk?

The Problem is reproducible on 10.11 (El Capitan), has ocurred to several people over large period of time and seems to be related specifically to HFS filesystem.

- [Cannot delete/rename/move a file from Windows with a special character](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7409456?tstart=0)
- [Can't delete a file](https://discussions.apple.com/message/2722099#2722099)

Reading several posts about the problem, usually the discussuon ends  without solutions. One way to try to solve this seems to boot the mac with an older OSX version, i.e. 10.6 - which still contains the "clri" tool. On my mac, running El Capitan, clri does not exist anymore.

[OSX 10.6.2 - man page for clri (osx section 8)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/8/clri/)

clri deletes a file by iNode number, which you can find out for the offending file by using "ls -li" from the terminal.

Be careful though since this might mess up your computer, do a backup first.

Another solution might be to boot from a Live CD and use a Disk-Editor to manually change the filename directly on the Disk, this would involve studying the exact way filenames are stored on disk by hfs+.

Alternative (safer) solution:

- Make complete Backup.
- Wipe Disk
- Restore backup without this file

The unicode null character is not allowed in filenames on HFS+ so i would consider it a bug, the Finder allows you to save files with that name.

Although you didn't mention HOW you are exactly are booting your Mac into Windows, i doubt that adding an extra abstraction layer (through MacDrive, a Windows HFS+ Driver or on a virtually shared mac volume as would be used by Fusion / Virtualbox etc.pp) would make things easier.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question if you can delete such a file in Windows, but to answer your questions, yes, I tried `rm`, `unlink`, and `find -delete` all of which returned "Invalid argument". I have disabled csrutil so it wouldn't matter, and yes, I am sure it's a file as I created it myself.

Comment: Saved a textedit document with that name, I also have a folder (with the same name) that I created normally (command + shift + n).

Comment: It's not a windows drive, it just want to delete the files through windows. The actual files are on an OS X Extended drive.

Comment: I have Windows installed on my Mac, I don't remember installing anything but my mac drive is visible to windows.

Comment: deleted my older comments since i edited my answer